# How to bake multiple objects into one?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, objects, texture-baking, baking

I have one unwrapped object (it's a log). I copied it via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and built a house. Then i merged all objects into one with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, but didnt do unwrap. Everything works fine.

Then I want to bake the lighting, so I do next:

1. Copy object.
2. Unwrap the copy.
3. Select both objects with copy active.
4. "Bake" combined with "Selected to active" checked.

But the result is very strange:

- It has no rotations.
- It has holes in some places.

Frankly, it looks awful and almost definetely i miss some general concept, but i can't figure it out.

Pls help :(

Comment: Can you post a your file or at least a picture?

Comment: As said the easist way is to join them, unwrap then ungroup them again.

Comment: Did you create another UV map (under "UV Maps" in the Object Data tab)?

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to help you if you had provided a blender scene or some screenshots.
If you want to bake multiple objects together, the way to go is the following (from what I understand you are doing some steps correctly, but might miss out on a few things to consider):

- create a separate uv channel for all objects and set it active
- note: every material must have a unconnected texture node with the texture you would like to bake to (this node has to be active)
- unwrap your objects: you can either select all objects and unwrap them together. (this will distribute the uv-coordinates for all objects on one uv-layout) Or you can manually unwrap the objects. but you need to make sure that they will not overlap with the uv coordinates from other objects you also want to bake)
- Make a copy of all objects and merge them
- hide the original objects
- bake (watch out that the island margin is not too big -> play around with it)

Edit: if you keep the original objects hidden, you can later apply the baked texture to all those objects and you still have them separate. Or you can apply the texture on the joined object, whatever you prefer