# Is there a way to take a mesh that has a material for every face and consolidate all the materials into one?

Tags: texture-baking

I am trying to preserve the face colors, of course, and trying to make the scene smaller on my disk. Due to there being exactly 69,393 faces, there are at least that many materials. The blend file on my disk is 705.6 megabytes. I REALLY need to reduce that, both for RAM and disk space. Is there a process or addon?

Keep in mind, I am not trying to bake a material. I am trying to bake all a mesh's materials to one image texture. Is this possible?

Comment: You could duplicate your object, give it one unique material with an Image Texture that will receive the bake, then bake the previous object (with all its materials) to the new one?

Comment: moonboots i can't tell what you mean by this. how will i do that?

Comment: Have you looked into baking multiple objects? Maybe see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49477/how-to-bake-multiple-objects-into-one